# Remove all punctuation from a csv after importing it

Tags: r, csv

Lets say I have a data frame (df) that contains the following data:

```
df = data.frame(name=c("David","Mark","Alice"),
income=c("5,000","10,00","$50.55"),
state=c("KS?","FL","CA;"))
```

I want to remove all punctuation from this data frame collectively. Of course, I could take each column as an individual vector and run a gsub command on it (see below), but I want to remove all punctuation in the whole data frame.

```
gsub("[?.;!¡¿·']", "", df$state)
```

Is there a way to specify this in R without writing a for loop or using an apply function to apply a function to each data frame column?

Comment: If you want to avoid looping over columns, it might be easier to use a command line tool like `sed` before importing the file into R. This could even be done from within R using `system()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @joran said, you can use `sed` like to `s`ubstitute out the punctuation you want to get rid of like this...

```
#  Writing your data out to a file
write.table( df , "~/input.txt" , sep = "\t" )

#  Reading it back in again, sans punctuation
read.table( pipe( paste0( "sed s'/[[:punct:]]//g' /Users/Simon/input.txt" ) ) , head=TRUE)
#   name income state
#1 David   5000    KS
#2  Mark   1000    FL
#3 Alice   5055    CA
```

`sed` processes your file line by line as it is being read into R. Using the `[[:punct:]]` regexp class will ensure you really do remove all punctuation.

And it can be done entirely within R. Lovely.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your criteria of "after importing", your condition of avoiding `apply` and family seems really arbitrary. I'd be interested in your logic for that.

Anyway, here's an alternative for fixing the problem *after you have already imported the data* that honors your peculiar condition:

- Create a new `class` that can be use by `colClasses` in `read.table` and family.
- Use `do.call(paste, ...)` to collapse your existing `data.frame` to a tab-separated character vector.
- Re-read that character vector, specifying `colClasses` this time.

Here is the above as an example:

```
setClass("spc")           ## Strip punctuation and return a character vector
setAs("character", "spc", function(from) 
  gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", from))
setClass("spn")           ## Strip punctuation and return a numeric vector
setAs("character", "spn", function(from) 
  as.numeric(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", from)))

## Use those `class`es in `colClasses`
out2 <- read.delim(text = do.call(paste, c(df, sep = "\t")), 
                   header = FALSE, colClasses = c("spc", "spn", "spc"))
str(out2)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ V1: chr  "David" "Mark" "Alice"
#  $ V2: num  5000 1000 5055
#  $ V3: chr  "KS" "FL" "CA"
```

Alternatively, if any tabular form will suffice, you can convert the data to a `matrix` and use `gsub` on that.

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", as.matrix(df))
#      name    income state
# [1,] "David" "5000" "KS" 
# [2,] "Mark"  "1000" "FL" 
# [3,] "Alice" "5055" "CA"
```

Comment: +1 what a novel way to go about this. Very interesting, thanks!